# Checking a dynamic referer URL in PHP to prevent access to a page

Tags: php, wordpress, referer

I am trying to prevent direct access to a webppage, I only want the visitors to be able to view the page if they got referred by a specific URL.

For example, visitor attempts to view the webpage https://example.com/restricted, if the visitor is not coming from https://example.com/redirect/***, the visitor should be redirected to the homepage.

Why am I using the asterix in my referrer URL? It's a dynamic(?) URL. By that I mean, the referrer URL could be https://example.com/redirect/514, but it could also be https://example.com/redirect/58613.

So basically, I would need to have a 'wildcard' to add to the end of the URL, instead of the number at the end. https://example.com/redirect/WILDCARDHERE? (That's what I think)

Note: I will use this code in my Wordpress functions file, I tried the Wordpress stack overflow, but didn't get any response, that's why I'm trying my luck here.

I've tried several things, but I'm pretty clueless.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
if ( ! is_page(464)) {
    return;
}

if (wp_get_referer() == 'https://example.com/redirect/') {
    return;
}

wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
exit;
})
```

Hope someone can provide me with the correct value!

Comment: do add wordpress tag if you using wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to check If referer starts with your domain or redirect keyword.
Example usage

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();
if ($referrer !== false && strpos($referer, "domain") === 0) {
      return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't really solve my question, users can for example be refered from my homepage and have access to the page while they shouldn't be able to. The code I pasted basically does this.
What I really need is to have a 'wildcard' for the randomly generated number at the end of the URL.

Comment: I really won't use this method because HTTP referer can easily be manipulated. If you insist on using this method you can use regular expressions for wildcard check.